# getting mysql dump 1045: Access denied error when trying to backup mysql database using sh script

Tags: mysql, linux, sh

here is my .sh script which will take backup of mysql database on every hour then upload on my s3 bucket

```
  GNU nano 6.2                                        backup-script.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Define variables
DB_HOST="localhost"
DB_USER="myusername"
DB_PASSWORD="mydpassowrd"
DB_NAME="mydb name"
S3_BUCKET="my s3 bucjet name"
BACKUP_FILENAME="backup.sql.gz"
EMAIL_ADDRESS=""
LOG_FILE="/root/backup-log.txt"


# Perform MySQL backup
mysqldump -h $DB_HOST -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME | gzip > $BACKUP_FILENAME

...others code
```

my backup is successfully uploaded but still now I am getting this error:

```
 Enter password: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
Completed 20 Bytes/20 Bytes (15 Bytes/s) with 1 file(s) remaining
```

I also add grant all permissions for the user.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: `DB_USER="myuser"` perhaps. Also watch shell quoting

Comment: @danblack didn't got your point

Comment: `DB_USER="myusername"` != `TO 'myuser'@'%'` but I think you've hidden so many details inconsistently its hard to identify the problem.

Comment: `(using password: NO)` So it appears to be loosing your password

Comment: Can you try printing `-h $DB_HOST -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME | gzip > $BACKUP_FILENAME` Sorry not to familiar with .sh scripting

Comment: @RiggsFolly When run the above command  backup file is created and also my shell script uploads and creates a backup  but don't know why getting the error for shell scripts

Comment: @boyenec as RiggsFolly pointed out, the password is not being passed to the mysqldump utility. This is evidenced by the error message that says using password: NO. You need to figure out why the password is not there.